# How to add a folly function with arguments into an folly executor?

Tags: c++, multithreading, folly

I am trying to add some normal jobs which are folly::Function in folly::ThreadedExecutor. However, it appears that folly::ThreadedExecutor only provide interface to accept **`folly::Function<void()>`**. How could I add a function with arguments and outputs?

```
// Here's a simple code segment

#include <folly/executors/ThreadedExecutor.h>
#include <folly/futures/Future.h>

int my_func(int t) {
   sleep(t);
   return 1;
}

int main() {
   folly:ThreadedExecutor executor;
   folly:Function<int(int)> job = my_func;
   executor.add(job);  
}
```

Compile with `gcc -o folly_executor --std=c++14 -g -O0 -Wall folly_executor.cc -lgtest -lfolly -lpthread -lglog -lgflags -ldl -ldouble-conversion -levent -liberty -lboost_context`

The error says the mismatch of `add` function prototype in `executor` and  `my_func`. Following is the compilation error.

```
In file included from folly_executor.cc:2:0:
/usr/local/include/folly/executors/ThreadedExecutor.h:67:8: note: 
candidate: virtual void folly::ThreadedExecutor::add(folly::Func)
   void add(Func func) override;
        ^~~
/usr/local/include/folly/executors/ThreadedExecutor.h:67:8: note:   no 
known conversion for argument 1 from 'folly::Function<int(int)>' to 
'folly::Func {aka folly::Function<void()>}'
```

I wonder that if the restriction of add function prototype has necessary reason. If not, it must be a right way to do it.

By the way, the [tutorial](https://code.fb.com/developer-tools/futures-for-c-11-at-facebook/) and document on Github always use folly::executor with folly:Future. Should I use folly:Function in that way?

Comment: When creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please make sure it's the actual code that generates the error(s) you have! The current code you show will have errors, but not the ones you ask about.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have edited my question. I will provide further extra information if it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Alex Bakulin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53088091/6686803). I solve my problem with `folly::Future` interface, following is my sample code. In my case I use `Future` with `AtomicHashMap` together. Using `Future` one could feed input and access output easily with `folly::via` and `std::bind`. However I am still confused about why they narrow down the usage of `Folly::Function` and expect it would only be used in storing a callable object without any input and output.

```
#include <folly/executors/CPUThreadPoolExecutor.h>
#include <folly/futures/Future.h>
#include <folly/AtomicHashMap.h>


folly::Future<int> my_func(int t, folly::AtomicHashMap<int, int>& ahm) {
    ahm.insert(std::make_pair(t, t*2));
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    folly::CPUThreadPoolExecutor executor(8);
    folly::AtomicHashMap<int, int> ahm(4096);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        folly::Future<int> f = folly::via(&executor, std::bind(my_func, i, std::ref(ahm)));
    }
    executor.join();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        auto ret = ahm.find((i));
        int r = ret != ahm.end() ? ret->second : 0;
        std::cout << i << "th result is "<< r << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already figured it all out yourself, but I'll put an answer just for completeness. `ThreadedExectutor` is a really low-level thing that just runs stuff for you in separate threads. When you schedule some function to run, you don't have much control over when and what it returns. If all you need to do is to make the function invocation happen in a separate thread, you could wrap this invocation in an anonymous function with the signature that the executor expects:

```
executor.add([]() { my_func(123); });
```

If your goal is also to capture the output of the invocation, then you're going to be better off using [futures](https://code.fb.com/developer-tools/futures-for-c-11-at-facebook/), which are at a higher level of abstraction and give you a much more rich set of primitives to work with.